# Gradle script for BB10 android runtime

Tags: gradle, blackberry-10, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, blackberry-android

I use android runtime  for generating  BB10 builds now am thinking of moving on to android studio from eclipse so can anyone tell me the gradle script for bb10 so that I can use that to create BB10 builds in android studio .

Thanks.

Comment: Hi user3517929, did you get the answer for this ? if so can you please post the answer in here?